# Exceptional Simple Jordan Algebra Cross product

Tags: linear-algebra, abstract-algebra

Does anyone happen to know of an explicit construction of the cross product on the exceptional simple Jordan algebra, or perhaps a reference?

Context: I'm trying to see if $(D^* a)X b + a X (D^*b) = -D(a X b)$, where $a,b$ are in the Jordan algebra, 'X' is the cross product, $D$ is a random element of the structure algebra (ie something of the form $L_a + [L_b,L_c])$, and $*$ is the 'transpose' with respect to the trace form on the algebra.

Comment: Welcome to MSE! It really helps readability to format questions using MathJax (see FAQ). Regards